# Can I write $f[i-1] \neq value$ instead of $s=i-1 \Rightarrow f[s] \neq value$

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I have got the following statement:

$$s=i-1 \Rightarrow f[s] \neq value$$.

This states that the element $f[i-1]$ does not equal $value$. Thats why I am wondering if I can use the following equivalence

$$s=i-1 \Rightarrow f[s] \neq value \Leftrightarrow f[i-1] \neq value$$

It feels right but I am not sure if it is formally correct. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Cf. [substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties)

Comment: Thanks.. So regarding to the "basic property" section. It says "if $a = b$, then $F(a) = F(b)$". That means for me if $s=i-1$ then $f[s] = f[i-1]$ and the equivalence shown above is correct. Right? I am not sure because of the implication. Can I just delete that implication like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand: it would be clearer if you stated the actual question in the body and not just in the title. Also, I don't know why you are using square brackets for function applications and I will use round brackets as is customary. Given that change of notation and looking at the question in your title:

$$s=i-1 \Rightarrow f(s) \neq value$$

is equivalent to:

$$s=i-1 \Rightarrow f(i - 1) \neq value$$

But that is only equivalent to $f(i - 1) \neq value$ in a context where you either know that $s = i - 1$ or you know that $f(i - 1) \neq value$.

Comment: Thanks. I used the square brackets, because these equations are part of proofing the correctness of an algorithm. $f[s]$ describes the element $s$ of the field $f$. But of course, you are right I could have used round brackets instead. I will not just delete this implication as shown. I will argue within the context that this statement is true, as you adviced.